# Scope manage_pages permission request doesn't appear for testers on login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement a login button for my app that will ask the user to grant my app permission of 'manage_pages'
I added the following button:

`<fb:login-button
    scope="public_profile,email,manage_pages"
    onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>`

Since i didn't do any action in my app developer settings to add manage_pages i added a user to my testers Role.
When the tester user clicks the login button he doesn't get asked for his approval to grant manage_pages permission.
Why doesn't he get asked for manage_pages?

Is it because i need to configure it before in the developer settings? how can i do such thing?

I also attempted to make a test app of the original app so it would be in development mode, but the problem persists.
I also tried to swap the button to the following JS function:

`FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});`

It prompts the test user to grant the app basic info, but not manage_pages permission

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not really a problem.
I haven't seen the manage_pages permission request on the login process, so i haven't clicked "approve" because i was expecting to see manage_pages.

But once i approved the unsufficient permissions request i got asked for ANOTHER permission approval of manage_pages